# Socket not listening on connection event

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am finding it hard to connect to socket and I don't know what I am doing wrong
This is the entry point:

```
    const { PORT } = process.env;
    const server = http.createServer(this.app);

    const io = new SocketServer(server);

    io.startSever();

    server.listen(PORT || this.port, () => {
      console.log(`App listening on the port ${this.port}`);
    });
```

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';


class SocketServer {
 public io;
 constructor(server: any) {
  this.io = new Server(server, {
   cors: {
    origin: '*',
   },
  });
  // console.log(this.io);
 }

 startSever() {

  this.io.on('connect_error', (err) => {
   console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
  });

  this.io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   console.log('Socket connected successfully');
  });
 }
}

export default SocketServer;
```

It is not listening for the on connection so the logging never happens

Comment: The detail the question provides is basically  an unspecific "does not work" and then throws in some undocumented code. This does not provide a solid problem description and is thus missing the base for a helpful answer. Please describe exactly what you expect to happen and what happens instead, with enough detail to be reproducible by others.